# Can't get JQuery working on my site?

Tags: jquery, html

I can't get any JQuery code to work on my website, in particular, slidebox. By the JQuery is not working, I mean, in this case, that when I click on a link, a tag, nothing happens, when really a lightbox should be appearing.

Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4 /jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        Shadowbox.init();
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
        <a class="logo" href="..."></a>
        <h1><strong>...</strong>iOS Developer</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="portfolio">
        <a href="img/image.png" rel="shadowbox" title="SocialPic - Coming fall 2011"><img src="img/image2.png" /></a>
        <a title="SocialPic - Coming fall 2011" href="img/SocialPic-iPhone.png"><img src="img/image2.png" /></a>
        <a title="SocialPic - Coming fall 2011" href="img/SocialPic-iPhone.png"><img src="img/image2.png" /></a>
        <a title="SocialPic - Coming fall 2011" href="img/SocialPic-iPhone.png"><img src="img/image2.png" /></a>
    </section>
```

Comment: which browser? which lightbox do you use (link)?

Comment: Just type the $ sign in the console, this will tell you if jquery is loaded or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect it isn't working because there is a space in the path to jQuery.  Remove the space and try again. :)

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js